# Android. CheckBox. Как получить конечную цену продуктов

Tags: android, checkbox

Доброго времени суток!

Уже который час сижу и ломаю голову, как сделать конечную сумму продуктов в корзине.
Использую кастомный RecyclerView, в которой: картинка, цена, наименование и CheckBox.
Должно получиться что-то на подобие корзины из мобильного приложения AliExpress.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Скриншоты моего приложения:
[image: скрин 1]

[image: скрин 2]

Comment: Суммируйте стоимость всего что есть в корзине. А чекбокс нужен для того, чтобы удалить чекнутый объект из корзины.

Answer (score 1):

Ну в вашей ситуации стоит писать более развёрнутый ответ. И так начнём:

1. Вам нужна цена всех продуктов:

   `val sum = 0
   for(good in goodsList) {
       sum = sum + good.price
   }`
2. Вам нужна цена по checkBox, тут немного сложнее, но также ничего сложного, делаете в onBindView(), лучше в holdere, но с этим вы уже сами разберётесь:

   `val good = goods[postion]
   val sum = 0
   checkBox.setOnCheckedChangedListener { _, isChecked ->
       if(isChecked) {
           sum = sum + good.price
       } else {
           sum = sum - good.price
       }
   }`
3. Возвращаем цену в активити/фрагмент: 
   Здесь сами уже попробуйте обдумать, но идея следующая, создаём интерфейс, например: `OnSumPriceChanged {}`,  подписываемся на него в Активити и обновляете UI, вызываете его в `checkBox.setOnCheckedChangedListener {}`, после обновления суммы, ввиде например: updateSumPrice(sum)